# MS CRM 2011 - Entity form designer preview doesn't use updated javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, jscript

I was editing an entity form and updated the Javascript used in the form without leaving the form designer window. I clicked save and then preview but there was no sign of my Javascript changes. I looked at the source files for the preview and the Javascript file being used was the version before my changes.

The only way I seem able to test Javascript changes is by publishing them first, which is undesirable.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. This is probably because; the JavaScript is actually contained in a separate web resource and you are previewing the form changes, not the web resource changes.

I would suggest just publishing the JavaScript web resource after you update it, its probably the easiest way to handle it, its the way I work.

Comment: But if I break something in the Javascript then my live environment is broken and my users will be unhappy.

Comment: Why would you be developing in your live environment?

Comment: I understand that I can test in a separate organisation but surely the point of the form preview is to test the form, including the Javascript.

Comment: Maybe, I didn't build those features, Microsoft did.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the real world it isn't always worth creating a development environment for a few minor changes to a live system. I expect that was why Microsoft included the preview feature and I understand now that it has limitations.

Comment: Copy the form, set roles so only you can use it. Add new web resource eg js_AccountForm_test and copy/paste the js text from the old web resource. On your form copy, switch out the web resource to use the new copy of your scripts. Now you can change your scripts, publish them and test on a real (not preview) version of your copy of the form. You can even UAT this way by having a security role called "UAT" which gives access to the form (nothing else) and assigning it to one or more users temporarily. Once happy, copy and paste the JS text from test to live web resource.